Using the R arrow package to read private Google Cloud Parquet File
I am currently trying to read a parquet file from Google Cloud Storage using the R programming language and the arrow package. I am using this documentation here:
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/fs.html
I have no issues replicating the example for the public buckets. But I am confused by the documentation around Google Storage for private files. The below screenshot seems to imply I need to get a Google Cloud access and secret key, but I think access and secret keys are related to AWS and not Google Cloud.

I am able to autenicathenicate and interact with the Google Storage bucket with other packages
gar_auth_service(json_file="~/.ssh/myjson.json")

But the below code to read in a private parquet file from Google Cloud always times out.
library(arrow)
dat <- read_parquet("gs://mybucket/mypath/myfile.parquet?retry_limit_seconds=10t")

I am able to connect to the bucket via the file system commands:
fs <- GcsFileSystem$create(json_credentials="~/.ssh/myjson.json")

So I don't think it is a credential/access issues. I just think i need to modify this piece of code but I am unsure what modification I should use.
library(arrow)
dat <- read_parquet("gs://mybucket/mypath/myfile.parquet?retry_limit_seconds=10t")


Is there a reason you feel its necessary to use the URI method when the documentation you link to says that in most cases it's better just to pass the file system object from gs_bucket() directly to read_parquet()?

In general, when I have done this, the flow is (1) create file system object representing the bucket with gs_bucket() and then do something like (2) read_parquet(bkt$path(<path>)). The one gotcha that I've run into in the past is that the json credentials had to be passed directly, not as a path. That was a bug that may have been fixed in later versions.

@joran Thank you! That worked. I was have a lot of trouble with gs_bucket(). I think that was the issue for me some reason. But switching to "GcsFileSystem" worked for some reason.

Thank you @joran for all the help. I was have a lot of trouble with gs_bucket(). I think that was the issue for me some reason. But switching to GcsFileSystem worked for some reason.
See reproducible example below:
# Bring in libraries
library(arrow)

# Check that the installed version of arrow supports GCS (should return TRUE)
arrow_with_gcs()

# Authenicate with service account json file
fs <- GcsFileSystem$create(json_credentials="~/.ssh/myserviceaccountfile.json")

# Read in parquet from path
main_file <- fs$path("mybucket/mypath/myfile.parquet")
main_dat <- read_parquet(main_file)

# And you should be good to work with your data!

